# How to sorting nvarchar column after 4 character?

Tags: sql-server

I have a `nvarchar` column and when I am selecting using below query this it is giving below output -

```
SELECT DISTINCT [VERSION]   
FROM IMPORT.BUDGETIMPORT 
WHERE VERSION LIKE 'Test'+'18'+'%' 
ORDER BY [VERSION] ASC
```

Output:

```
Test18
Test18.1
Test18.10
Test18.2
Test18.3
Test18.4
Test18.5
Test18.6
```

I want to order it by number while selecting -

```
Test18
Test18.1
Test18.2
Test18.3
Test18.4
Test18.5
Test18.6
Test18.10
```

How could I sorted based on number only.

Comment: 18.1 and 18.10 are same for numeric data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one.

Order first by length of the string and then by the string itself.

**Query**

```
SELECT [VERSION]
FROM IMPORT.BUDGETIMPORT 
WHERE [VERSION] LIKE 'Test18'+'%' 
GROUP BY [VERSION]  
ORDER BY LEN([VERSION]), [VERSION];
```

**[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/73939/1)**

Comment: You missed DISTINCT

Comment: This query has error - ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: This query has error - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'

Comment: @user2318170 Sorry, missed out.

Answer (score 0):

For numeric Datatypes, 18.1 is same as 18.10
and for string datatypes, 18.10 will come before 18.2

Try the below method to get your expected result

```
declare @t table
(
    [version] nvarchar(50)
)

insert into @t
values('Test18'),
('Test18.1'),
('Test18.10'),
('Test18.2'),
('Test18.3'),
('Test18.4'),
('Test18.5'),
('Test18.2'),
('Test18.3'),
('Test18.4'),
('Test18.5'),
('Test18.6')

;with cte
as
(
    select 
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [VERSION] ORDER BY [VERSION]),
        ln = LEN([VERSION]),
        [version] 
        from @t 
)
select
    *
    from cte
        WHERE rn = 1
        order by ln
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to perform it is casting the version as `float`;

```
SELECT DISTINCT [VERSION], cast(SUBSTRING([VERSION], 5, 10) as float) as VersionAsFloat
FROM IMPORT.BUDGETIMPORT 
WHERE VERSION LIKE 'Test'+'18'+'%' 
ORDER BY VersionAsFloat ASC
```